# How to use Selenium to scrape video transcription

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape transcripts from this video using Selenium but I could get the full transcription. I just can only get 1-by-1 sentences by clicking different times on the video. It takes a lot of time.
Can you help me get the full transcription from this website?

https://www.luyennghetienganh.com/learn-by-listening-level-1/1060-learn-english-by-listening-level-1-unit-001.html

Here is my code:

```
driver.get(https://www.luyennghetienganh.com/learn-by-listening-level-1/1060-learn-english-by-listening-level-1-unit-001.html)
engsubs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rabbit-lyrics__line")
[i.text for i in engsubs]
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXNYE.png)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use selenium for this. You can simply use **requests** & **bs4**.

Here is how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get("https://www.luyennghetienganh.com/learn-by-listening-level-1/1060-learn-english-by-listening-level-1-unit-001.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
transcripts = soup.find('div', {"class": "rabbit-lyrics lyric-1 col-1"}).text.strip().split('\n')

eng_sub = transcripts[0::2]
print(eng_sub)
```

end_sub:

```
['[00:00.04] First Snow Fall ', 'Today is November 26th.', 'It snowed all day today.', 'The snow is beautiful.', 'The snow finally stopped.', 'My sister and I are excited.', "My Mom doesn't like the snow.", 'My Mom has to shovel the drive way.', 'My sister and I get to play.', 'I put on my hat and mittens.', 'My Mom puts on my scarf.', 'My Mom zippers my jacket.', 'My sister puts on her hat and mittens.', 'My Mom puts on her scarf.', 'My Mom zippers her jacket.', 'My sister and I go outside.', 'We begin to make a snow man.', 'My Mom starts to shovel the snow.', 'My sister and I make snow angels.', 'My sister and I throw snowballs.', 'It starts to snow again.', 'We go inside for hot chocolate.']
```

[Update]

Using **Selenium** only:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.luyennghetienganh.com/learn-by-listening-level-1/1060-learn-english-by-listening-level-1-unit-001.html")

container = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.rabbit-lyrics__line')
eng_sub = [i.get_attribute('innerHTML') for i in container]
print(eng_sub)
```

end_sub:

```
[' First Snow Fall', 'Today is November 26th.', 'It snowed all day today.', 'The snow is beautiful.', 'The snow finally stopped.', 'My sister and I are excited.', "My Mom doesn't like the snow.", 'My Mom has to shovel the drive way.', 'My sister and I get to play.', 'I put on my hat and mittens.', 'My Mom puts on my scarf.', 'My Mom zippers my jacket.', 'My sister puts on her hat and mittens.', 'My Mom puts on her scarf.', 'My Mom zippers her jacket.', 'My sister and I go outside.', 'We begin to make a snow man.', 'My Mom starts to shovel the snow.', 'My sister and I make snow angels.', 'My sister and I throw snowballs.', 'It starts to snow again.', 'We go inside for hot chocolate.']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a great solution. However, can you explain why I can't use selenium to get the full transcription here? I'm new to Selenium. I use this to practice what I've learned about Selenium but I don't know why I can't get them all.

Comment: @ThanhHoàng I didn't say you can not use selenium, you can use it to get the same data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've never known about get_attribute('innerHTML'). I still have a lot to learn about Selenium.